# Change CSS Values Dynamically Via Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, css, function, css-animations, variable-assignment

I want to create a Javascript where an element's CSS values are declared from a function instead of within the stylesheet. Say I have three different DIVs:

```
<DIV id="block1">First</DIV>
<DIV id="block2">Second</DIV>
<DIV id="block3">Third</DIV>
```

And they all share the same animation properties.

```
#block1 {
  background: red;
}
#block2 {
  background: gold;
}
#block3 {
  background: green;
}

#block1, #block2, #block3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: mymove 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {transform: translateX(100px);}
  to {transform: translateX(0px);}
}
```

But I want each DIV to have its own animation movements. The duration could be longer, or the element might move differently. For example, block1 could be 4 seconds long, block2 goes three times its distance (making it a translateX of 300px), and block3 might move vertically instead of horizontally, so we go to translateY. There is even a chance that one of these blocks could have different X and Y values. That would mean writing more classes or IDs, and the filesize could get huge.

The Javascript code I'm planning will be called setStyle. It plans to accept four values: *a*/timing for animation-timing-function, *b*/period for animation-duration, *c*/x for translateX and *d*/y for translateY.

As I want this function to take off the instant the page is loaded without user input like a button, I thought I could call it through onload:

***HTML BODY***

```
<DIV id="block1" onload="setStyle(4s)">First</DIV>
<DIV id="block2" onload="setStyle(300px,0)">Second</DIV>
<DIV id="block3" onload="setStyle(0,100px)">Third</DIV>
```

The problem I'm having is I don't know how to get the values into Javascript. What you will see below is a mixture of known codes and pseudo-code that will be changed into real code later:

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
function setStyle(id,a,b,c,d) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(id);
    if (a exists)
        elm.style.animationDuration = a;
    if (b exists)
        elm.style.animationTimingFunction = b;
    if (c exists via x,0 where x is x-coordinate in pixels)
        elm.style.transform = "translateX(c)";
    if (d exists via 0,y where y is y-coordinate in pixels)
        elm.style.transform = "translateX(d)";
    if (c and d exists)
        elm.style.transform = "translate(c,d)";
}
```

What do I need to do so that the values found in onload are properly parsed, and that the following happen:

1. block1's duration is 4 seconds
2. block2 moves 300px in the x-axis
3. block3 moves 100px in the y-axis

Comment: What do you mean by "c exists via x,0"?

Comment: That is the format the user would have to type if they wanted just the x-coordinate for c. Without the comma and 0, the planned parser won't know if you're specifying for an x-coord or a y-coord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need javascript for this. You could pull this off with inline styles and/or custom properties.

```css
:root {
  --y-start: 0;
  --y-end: 0;
  --x-start: 0;
  --x-end: 100px;
  --dur: 3s;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: gold;
}

.three {
  background: green;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: mymove var(--dur, 3s) ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {transform: translate(var(--x-start, 100px), var(--y-start, 100px));}
  to {transform: translate(var(--x-end, 0px), var(--y-end, 0px));}
}
```

```html
<div class="block one" style="--dur: 4s;">First</div>
<div class="block two" style="--x-end: 300px;">Second</div>
<div class="block three" style="--x-end: 0; --y-end: 100px;">Third</div>

<!--
block1's duration is 4 seconds
block2 moves 300px in the x-axis
block3 moves 100px in the y-axis
-->
```